# Format JSON array data

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

Table with sample data:

```
create table tbl_jsdata
(
id int,
p_id int,
field_name text,
field_value text 
);

insert into tbl_jsdata values
(1,101,'Name','Sam'),
(2,101,'City','Dubai'),
(3,101,'Pin','1235'),
(4,101,'Country','UAE'),
(5,102,'Name','Sam'),
(6,102,'City','Dubai'),
(7,102,'Name','Sam Jack');
```

json_agg query:

```
select p_id,
    json_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object(field_name,field_value)) jsdata
from tbl_jsdata
group by p_id;
```

Getting Result:

```
p_id    jsdata
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 [{"City": "Dubai"}, {"Country": "UAE"}, {"Name": "Sam"}, {"Pin": "1235"}]
102 [{"City": "Dubai"}, {"Name": "Sam"}, {"Name": "Sam Jack"}]
```

Expected Result:

```
p_id    jsdata
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 [{"City": "Dubai","Country": "UAE","Name": "Sam","Pin": "1235"}]
102 [{"City": "Dubai","Name": "Sam"}, {"Name": "Sam Jack"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function:

```
postgres=# select p_id, json_object_agg(field_name, field_value) from tbl_jsdata group by p_id;
┌──────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ p_id │                             json_object_agg                             │
╞══════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│  101 │ { "Name" : "Sam", "City" : "Dubai", "Pin" : "1235", "Country" : "UAE" } │
│  102 │ { "Name" : "Sam", "City" : "Dubai", "Name" : "Sam Jack" }               │
└──────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Nope! Need it in form of ARRAY `[ { } ]`

Comment: I afraid so this is not possible by SQL query - your data are not well normalized and depends on order - so you cannot to processed it by relational algebra. You miss one column for aggregation. SQL cannot to detect so your object starts with attribute 'Name'

Comment: @MAK if you really need an array with a single object, then turn the result of `json_object_agg()` into an array: `json_build_array(json_object_agg(...)) as ...`